# SciPy optimize.minimize() usage with many variables and without analytical computeable gradient

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, gradient

I have following problem to solve:

Given a function, which takes a vector of variables as a parameter, find values that minimize function return value. The size of the input vector is between `10^3` and `10^5` elements. The analytical gradient formula is not provided.

Sounds like problem for `scipy.optimize.minimize()`; however, due to the number variables and lack of gradient function the calculation is incredibly slow and for more than 2000 parameters does not converge.

I have code familiar to the code below (in fact using this for image registration, but the problem is more general):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def opt_fun(smth1, smth2, con1, con2, con3, con4):
    def inner_opt_fun(arguments):
        arg1 = np.reshape(arguments[0:con1*con2], (con1, con2))
        arg2 = np.reshape(arguments[con1*con2:], (con3, con4))
        result = some_func(smth1, arg1, arg2)
        error = calc_error(result, smth2)
        return error
    return inner_opt_fun

fun = opt_fun(smth1, smth2, con1, con2, con3, con4)
start_args = generate_start_arguments()
bounds = get_bounds() # define some bounds to solver
bounds = reshape_bound(bounds) # to get 1xN vector
options = some_options() # solver options

optimized = optimize.minimize(fun, start_args, bounds=bounds, options=options)
```

`some_func` calculates transformation of variable `smth1`.

`calc_error` calculates some kind of error between `smth2` and `result` returned by `some_func`.

In general, the optimizer should approximate gradient (or other quantity, which can lead to finding local minimum) of `error` with respect to `arguments` vector.

This code works fine when the length of vector `start_args` is below 10. However, the more variables are involved the more strange things the `optimize.minimize` function performs. During each call of `fun` it changes only one element of `arguments` vectors (scaling is not the issue there - I perform it elsewhere).

For example, if the initialized vector is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]`, after first iteration the optimizer tries something like `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]`, then `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0]` - for me it is rather brute force approach.

I have tried different optimizers (BFGS, L-BFGS-B, Powell, Nelder-Mead - I am not a mathematician, so do not really understand how they work inside), but they simply do not converge to anything.

The question is - where could the problem lie on? What can I do to enforce convergence?